# Crudrepository tuple from multiple entities

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, crud

I have two entities,  say Transaction and Customer and I want to implement a query which will join these two tables and return result as a list of tuples, like:

```
@Query("select new ExportTransactionTuple(t,c) from Transaction t left join Account a left join Customer c")
List<ExportTransactionTuple> findByTransactionBankingDateWithCustomer();


@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class ExportTransactionTuple {

private Transaction transaction;
private Customer customer;
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `ExportTransactionTuple` is not managed by the `EntityManager` so your jpql query will not work. You should devide your query and then aggreagte the results

Comment: you are wrong, jpql allows to use DTO objects

Comment: better use Interface  projection

Comment: can you post an example? Not sure how to use projections in JPQL query string.